# Scrape with BeautifulSoup in a line

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner in python, so what i want to do is to scrape a website with BeautifulSoup. In a small part of the page source this is the html:

```
<table class="swift" width="100%">
   <tr>
     <th class="no">ID</th>
     <th>Bank or Institution</th>
     <th>City</th>
     <th class="branch">Branch</th>
     <th>Swift Code</th>
   </tr>   <tr>
     <td align="center">101</td>
     <td>BANK LEUMI ROMANIA S.A.</td>
     <td>CONSTANTA</td>
     <td>(CONSTANTA BRANCH)</td>
     <td align="center"><a href="/romania/dafbro22cta/">DAFBRO22CTA</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="center">102</td>
     <td>BANK LEUMI ROMANIA S.A.</td>
     <td>ORADEA</td>
     <td>(ORADEA BRANCH)</td>
     <td align="center"><a href="/romania/dafbro22ora/">DAFBRO22ORA</a></td>
   </tr>
```

I managed to scrape them but this is the output:

```
ID
Bank or Institution
City
Branch
Swift Code

101
BANK LEUMI ROMANIA S.A.
CONSTANTA
(CONSTANTA BRANCH)
DAFBRO22CTA


102
BANK LEUMI ROMANIA S.A.
ORADEA
(ORADEA BRANCH)
DAFBRO22ORA
```

When i actually want it like this:

```
ID, Bank or Institution, City, Branch, Swift Code

101, BANK LEUMI ROMANIA S.A., CONSTANTA, (CONSTANTA BRANCH) ,DAFBRO22CTA

102, BANK LEUMI ROMANIA S.A., ORADEA, (ORADEA BRANCH), DAFBRO22ORA
```

This is my code:

```
base_url = "https://www.theswiftcodes.com/"
nr = 0
page = 'page'
country = 'Romania'
while nr < 4:
    url_country = base_url + country + '/' + 'page' + "/" + str(nr) + "/"
    pages = requests.get(url_country)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pages.text, 'html.parser')

    for script in soup.find_all('script'):
        script.extract()

    tabel = soup.find_all("table")
    text = ("".join([p.get_text() for p in tabel]))
    nr += 1
    print(text)

    file = open('swiftcodes.txt', 'a')
    file.write(text)
    file.close()

    file = open('swiftcodes.txt', 'r')
    for item in file:
        print(item)
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

str = """<table class="swift" width="100%">
   <tr>
     <th class="no">ID</th>
     <th>Bank or Institution</th>
     <th>City</th>
     <th class="branch">Branch</th>
     <th>Swift Code</th>
   </tr>   <tr>
     <td align="center">101</td>
     <td>BANK LEUMI ROMANIA S.A.</td>
     <td>CONSTANTA</td>
     <td>(CONSTANTA BRANCH)</td>
     <td align="center"><a href="/romania/dafbro22cta/">DAFBRO22CTA</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="center">102</td>
     <td>BANK LEUMI ROMANIA S.A.</td>
     <td>ORADEA</td>
     <td>(ORADEA BRANCH)</td>
     <td align="center"><a href="/romania/dafbro22ora/">DAFBRO22ORA</a></td>
   </tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(str)

for i in soup.find_all("tr"):
    result = ""
    for j in i.find_all("th"): # find all the header tags
        result += j.text + ", "
    for j in i.find_all("td"): # find the cell tags
        result += j.text + ", "
    print(result.rstrip(', '))
```

Output:

```
ID, Bank or Institution, City, Branch, Swift Code
101, BANK LEUMI ROMANIA S.A., CONSTANTA, (CONSTANTA BRANCH), DAFBRO22CTA
102, BANK LEUMI ROMANIA S.A., ORADEA, (ORADEA BRANCH), DAFBRO22ORA
```

Comment: Can you try to update it in the code please? it's a bit hard to understand it like this.

Comment: Well there is only 2 things in the code. Iterate over all the `tr` tags. Inside a `tr` tag iterate over either the `td` tags or the `th` tags, and store the text values in the `result` variable. And at each end of the `tr` iteration print them out. The `strip` thing is just a string manipulation to remove the commas

Comment: So your code should be put between print(text) and file = open('swiftcodes.txt', 'a')

Comment: I dont know what is the end goal. You pointed a desired output. This code outputs the desired one. If you want to store it in a file you can easily find solutions for that. If you want to store the header and the other in separate files that can easily be done by not storing the values in `result`, but printing it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.theswiftcodes.com/united-states/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
rows = soup.find(class_="swift").find_all('tr')
th = [th.text for th in rows[0].find_all('th')]
print(th)
for row in rows[1:]:
    cell = [i.text for i in row.find_all('td', colspan=False)]
    print(cell)
```

out:

```
['ID', 'Bank or Institution', 'City', 'Branch', 'Swift Code']
['1', '1ST CENTURY BANK, N.A.', 'LOS ANGELES,CA', '', 'CETYUS66']
['2', '1ST PMF BANCORP', 'LOS ANGELES,CA', '', 'PMFAUS66']
['3', '1ST PMF BANCORP', 'LOS ANGELES,CA', '', 'PMFAUS66HKG']
['4', '3M COMPANY', 'ST. PAUL,MN', '', 'MMMCUS44']
['5', 'ABACUS FEDERAL SAVINGS BANK', 'NEW YORK,NY', '', 'AFSBUS33']
[]
['6', 'ABBEY NATIONAL TREASURY SERVICES LTD US BRANCH', 'STAMFORD,CT', '', 'ANTSUS33']
['7', 'ABBOTT LABORATORIES', 'ABBOTT PARK,IL', '', 'ABTTUS44']
['8', 'ABBVIE, INC.', 'CHICAGO,IL', '', 'ABBVUS44']
['9', 'ABEL/NOSER CORP', 'NEW YORK,NY', '', 'ABENUS3N']
```